# Outer join send a case column in function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, case, outer-join

I have this query in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    t.acc_no, 
    t.[group],
    t.maxgroup, t.amount, 
    t1.assigned,
    taken = CASE 
               WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL   
               ELSE t.amount 
            END, 
    [left] = CASE 
                WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL  
                ELSE (t.maxgroup - t1.assigned) 
             END 
FROM 
    Testtable t
OUTER APPLY 
    TestApply1(t.acc_no, t.[group], [left]) t1
```

and I am trying to send the column in my function, but I get an error saying invalid name [left], I need a way to somehow send that derived column in my function. How can I go about doing that.

```
ALTER FUNCTION TestApply1 
    (@accountNo INT, @group VARCHAR(30), @left INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        (SELECT 
             assigned = SUM(CASE 
                               WHEN t1.amount > t1.maxgroup THEN t1.maxgroup  
                               ELSE t1.Amount 
                            END) 
        FROM 
            Testtable t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.acc_no = @accountNo AND t1.[group] <= @group)
    GO
```

Comment: Can you put the CASE logic inside the function and pass both `assigned` and `maxgroup` columns?

Comment: Case logic is dependent upon the returns from the function, so I dont think I can put that in.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize assigned was a return value. How can the output of the function be in the case statement with the input value? Unless I am mistaken, I'm pretty sure this needs a 2 part query like a CTE.

Comment: How to do it in cte? I am trying that too but still stuck

Comment: i don't think you can use [Left} in the function as value of [left] is being calculated from t1 and data of t1 is being calculated using [left]. So both seems to be dependent on each other, in your query. Can you provide details on what is expected output from this query. Sample table data and expected sample query output will help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi. A SELECT clause happens after FROM etc. It is applied to rows coming from the rest of the query. So it cannot be used to determine those rows. The column names in FROM etc are columns of rows of a single FROM table or the cross product of two JOINed tables. Read about the meaning of SELECT statements. Read about using assignment. Please read & act on [mcve]. So far you don't actually say how desired output is a function of input, you just give some vague short unhelpful phrases & some wrong queries. PS Goolge 'stackexchange comment notifications' to learn how to notify via @.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a normal definition for `left`, you would just use two levels of `apply`:

```
SELECT t.acc_no, t.[group], t.maxgroup, t.amount, t1.assigned,
       taken = (CASE WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL ELSE t.amount END),
       v.[left]
FROM Testtable t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL  
                   ELSE t.maxgroup - t1.assigned
              END)
     ) v([left]) OUTER APPLY -- awful name for a column
    TestApply1(t.acc_no, t.[group], v.[left]) t1;
```

However your definition depends on the result of the function.  Hence, what you want to do is ill-specified.  You cannot do what you want.  It doesn't make sense.